# Is there a way to sum the same column depend of another one?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called "menergy" with the next structure and data example:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
time | m_value | pt_periode | meter_id_meter | mtype_id_type |
--------------------------------------------------------------
t1   | 10      |  0         |      1         |      24       |
t1   |  5      |  0         |      1         |      25       |
t1   | 15      |  0         |      1         |      26       |
t1   | 20      |  0         |      1         |      27       |
t1   | 500     |  0         |      1         |      0002     |
```

There are 4 types of `mtype` so in case of mType = 24, 25, 26, 27 and not 0002, and the condition: `same time, same pt_periode, same meter_id` sum their `m_value`.
So for example a condition could be:

```
  (meter_id_meter = 1 and mtype_id_type = 24 and pt_periode = 0) or
  (meter_id_meter = 1 and mtype_id_type = 25 and pt_periode = 0) or
  (meter_id_meter = 1 and mtype_id_type = 26 and pt_periode = 0) or
  (meter_id_meter = 1 and mtype_id_type = 27 and pt_periode = 0)
```

So with the last example of data the result I want is : 10 + 5 + 15 + 20 =`50`. So I want to get 50 with the operation
I've read about IF condition and JOIN, but it needs to create another table. However, I've tryed the next but I had a syntax error:

```sql
SELECT
  timestampadd(month, -1, time_stamp) as "time",
  if ((meter_id_meter = 1 and mtype_id_type = 24 and pt_periode = 0) or
  (meter_id_meter = 1 and mtype_id_type = 25 and pt_periode = 0) or
  (meter_id_meter = 1 and mtype_id_type = 26 and pt_periode = 0) or
  (meter_id_meter = 1 and mtype_id_type = 27 and pt_periode = 0), SUM(m_value)) as "Q"
FROM menergy
```

Comment: You haven't actually stated what you are trying to do. Sample data and expected output would help clarify (as text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to your code seems you need sum the value where the if condition is true so try  using where

```
SELECT  timestampadd(month, -1, time_stamp) as "time", SUM(m_value)) as "Q"

FROM menergy
WHERE  (
  (meter_id_meter = 1 and mtype_id_type = 24 and pt_periode = 0) or
  (meter_id_meter = 1 and mtype_id_type = 25 and pt_periode = 0) or
  (meter_id_meter = 1 and mtype_id_type = 26 and pt_periode = 0) or
  (meter_id_meter = 1 and mtype_id_type = 27 and pt_periode = 0) 
)
group by  timestampadd(month, -1, time_stamp)
```

or simply

```
WHERE meter_id  = 1  AND pt_periode = 0 and mtype in (24,25,26,27)
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you should be using a where clause.

```
SELECT   SUM(m_value)) as "Q"
FROM menergy
where meter_id_meter = 1 and pr_periode = 0 and mtype_id_type in (2,25,26,27)
```

but I have no idea what you are trying to do with timestampadd(month, -1, time_stamp) as "time",